# Uniswap addLiquidityETH with large amount of ETH as parameter. What are the risks?

Tags: solidity, cryptocurrency, hardhat, erc20, uniswap

I am creating a smart contract that applies fees on uniswap buys / sells.
Portion of these fees are then added back to the Liquidity Pool(LP) and split among 3 recipients.

To do so and keep all fees dynamic I came up with the algorithm below. However I am unsure how safe that is since:

- It first swap all the collected fees into ETH.
- It then adds the LP share into the LP giving as a parameter ALL the ETH that has been obtain from the swap.
- Since it uses only portion of it. It automatically returns the unused ETH
- It then split them among the 3 recipient according to their share.

I like this approach for its ability to split all available ETH, even eventual ETH sent to the contract.

However the [uniswap documentation](https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#addliquidityeth) specifies: "Always adds assets at the ideal ratio, according to the price when the transaction is executed.". But I am unsure why and what could be the consequences of such a code.

Here is the code snippet.

```
    function _distributeFee() internal nonReentrant {
        swapTokensForETH(totalDevAmount + totalMarketingAmount + totalOwnerAmount + (totalLiquidity / 2));

        uint256 swapEthBalance = address(this).balance;

        if (totalLiquidity > 0) {
            addLiquidity((totalLiquidity / 2), swapEthBalance);
            totalLiquidity = 0;
        }

        swapEthBalance = address(this).balance;
        
        // send fees to their recipients
        uint256 devFeeETHAmount = swapEthBalance / (devFeePercent + marketingFeePercent + ownerFeePercent) * (devFeePercent);
        uint256 marketingFeeETHAmount = swapEthBalance / (devFeePercent + marketingFeePercent + ownerFeePercent) * (marketingFeePercent);
        uint256 ownerFeeETHAmount = swapEthBalance / (devFeePercent + marketingFeePercent + ownerFeePercent) * (ownerFeePercent);
        payable(devFeeRecipient).transfer(devFeeETHAmount);
        payable(marketingFeeRecipient).transfer(marketingFeeETHAmount);
        payable(ownerFeeRecipient).transfer(ownerFeeETHAmount);
    }

    function swapTokensForETH(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0, 
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        // approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // add the liquidity
        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            0, // slippage is unavoidable
            address(0), // send LP token to burn address
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
```

Looked into the uniswap doc but unsure what could be the consequences of this use

Comment: It's impossible to say whether this code is safe because we don't see the swapTokensForETH and addLiquidity functions. There are many ways how it can be unsafe, which go way beyond a single StackOverflow question, for example sandwich attacks when swapping and asset disbalance when adding liquidity. In short adding assets not in 50:50 balance is a suboptimal use of your capital; in the worst case (single asset only) it's simply a donation to the pool.

Comment: I edited my post to add the missing swapTokensForETH and addLiquidity functions.
Is it possible to give only one asset to the pool? Adding only one of the asset would ultimately change the token price which I believe is not possible. The pool will automatically fetch and get the necessary ETH. Indeed sandwich attack may be an issue. Are they common on LPs?

Comment: Unless the amounts that you add are very small, both adding and swapping will be sandwiched. All min amounts in your calls are set to zero. Though you're correct about addLiquidity always adding tokens in balance, if you're using the router instead of the pool directly, then unsafe adds are not possible.

Comment: I guess it's a common issue then. amounts will mostly be small but it can happens that they are big enough to be sandwiched attacked. Any specific measures to be taken against it? Or is it just a fatality that all smart contracts have to deal with? I'm currently looking into implementing anti front-run measures. Not sure if it's a common practice to have that in a smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of Risks to your approach,

1. you're not protecting again slippage, which allows attackers

   ```
    uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
        address(this),
        tokenAmount,
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
        0, // slippage is unavoidable
    //...
   ```
2. You're not setting the minimum amount out during the swaps.

```
uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, 
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
```

This means that if an attackers and mev bots can exploit, if they wrap your transactions they can flash loan, if they can't wrap them they can sandwich attack them.

Ideally you need a way to determine what the current market conditions are, whether thats leveraging chainlink, or having a trust provider update general quotes.